# Edit text parsing integer android

Tags: java, android

I am making android app and I have edit text surrounded by two buttons for increase and decrease 
[image]

and when I click the button increase or decrease for the first time it did not work but it start working from the second time
e.g if the number in edit text field is 50 when I press increase it still 50 when I press increase again it change to 51 and again it change to 52 and so on 
here is my java code for the two buttons

```
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (quantityEdit.getText().toString().equals("") || quantityEdit.getText().toString() == null) {
                quantityEdit.setText("0");
            } else {
                int a = Integer.parseInt(quantityEdit.getText().toString());
                int b = a + 1;

                quantityEdit.setText(String.valueOf(b));
            }

        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(quantityEdit.getText().toString());

            if (a >= 1) {
                int b = a - 1;

                quantityEdit.setText(String.valueOf(b));
            } else {

                quantityEdit.setText("0");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just an aside: You should consider using TextUtils.isEmpty to do a safe null check and empty string check of a string.

Comment: Where in your code do you set the initial value on your quantityEdit?  What is it set to?  Where in your code do you call the code you posted to set up your onClickListeners?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are checking for empty string or null in "add", but not in "sub". As [Michael Krause](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766755/michael-krause) said, you should use TextUtils.isEmpty(), and set a default value before performing add or sub operations.

If you are setting a default value elsewhere, please show your code.

Comment: As an aside, I'm surprised that your code isn't throwing an Exception when you try to parse the value if it's not set to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Consider refactoring your code like so

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        quantityEdit.setText(String.valueOf(getIntVal(quantityEdit) + 1));
    }
});

sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int value = getIntVal(quantityEdit);
        if (value > 0) {
            value--;
        }
        quantityEdit.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    }
});

// helper method to get the integer value of a TextView
private int getIntVal(TextView textView) {
    CharSequence rawValue = textView.getText();
    int value;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rawValue)) {
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(rawValue.toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            value = 0; 
            // TODO log / notify user
        }
    } else {
        value = 0;
    }
}
```

This way your initialization is handled in one place and it's more clear.

In any event, your first condition is wrong. You do a null check after trying to access the object (it's backwards). Have you checked your logs? This could throw an exception for a null value and "lose" the first click.